# Can I sell my SL4A app on Android Market

Tags: android, google-play, sl4a

I want to develop an application in Python for Android using SL4A and I want to know whether is possible to sell it as an application on Android Market.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should be able to after you have embedded your script into an APK. Take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/SharingScripts#Scripts_as_APKs) on the android-scripting wiki.

Answer (score 0):

But this APK still requires an installed interpreter which makes it not really comfortable. The APK includes a bootstrap installer but that does not work for me on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, and users seem okay with downloading the interpreter.

Comment: I've ported ALL my sl4a apps to eclipse apk, it embeds with the python interpreter:
A) Android Eye (Computer Vision):
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androideye.androideye)
B) See Say (OCR) Picture to Speach:
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.seesay.seesay)
C) [omit]
D) Standardized IQ Test:
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iqtest.iqtest)
E) Picture Drinks:
[link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picturedrinksnew.picturedrinksnew)